# trying to get this jquery code working in my rails app, function not being called

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I have some code which works fine as a html and js document. The function in the js script file is called correctly from the html doc. But when I transfer the same code to my rails, the function isn't called. If anyone could offer some advice, that would be great.

I have `//= require autocomplete` in my application.js file and I'm not getting any errors in my console. The page I yield to from application.html.erb is:

```
        <div data-role="page" id="myPage">

        <header data-role="header">
        <h1>remote data</h1>
        </header>

        <div data-role="content">
<h3>Cities worldwide</h3>
<p>After you enter <strong>at least three characters</strong> the autocomplete function will show all possible matches.</p>
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a city..." data-filter-theme="a"></ul>


    <script>
console.log("test1");
    $("#myPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) {
console.log("test2");
    initialize_autocomplete();
});

    </script>

        </div>

        <footer data-role="footer">

        </footer>

        </div>
```

I see 'test1' in console but 'test2' doesn't appear. And neither do test3 and test4, from autocomplete.js. My autocomplete.js is:

```
function initialize_autocomplete() {
    console.log("test3");
    $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        console.log("test4");
        var $ul = $( this ),
            $input = $( data.input ),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
        $ul.html( "" );
        if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
            $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    q: $input.val()
                }
            })
            .then( function ( response ) {
                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                    html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                });
                $ul.html( html );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application.html.erb the order was:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I changed this to:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

and now it works. Is that normal behaviour? I've been reading a bit about javascript_include_tag but if someone could put it in layman's terms I'd be grateful.

Comment: Basically you shouldn't use the script src tags. Declaring `javascript_include_tag` is sufficent for including all the necessary js files for you, because you usually include "application" and in the application.js itself, you're requiring all the other files, by listing them like `//= require jquery`, `//= require jquery_ujs` and so on. I hope that helps (btw, upvoted you, so you got past 10 rep, yay! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code with:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     // your functions defined here                  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for that, no, that didn't do it but just figured it out...will post my solution now.

Comment: In fact, they won't let me answer for another 8 hurs, because my rep is less than 10 :(

Comment: I upvoted your post, so now you have 8 points. One more upvote and... you're there :) Btw, it's a good practice to post answer when you figure out what was the problem :)

Comment: Stackoverflow works like this sometimes ;) Maybe someone downvoted it because I didn't address your problem.